# Create a date-index using pandas date range function, but skipping the week-end days (Sat and Sun)

Tags: pandas, date, date-range

I am trying to order some stock prices in a series, and would like to set the corresponding date as index. I did something like that to create the index :

```
date_index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods = 30, freq = 'D')
```

Thing is, my prices-list skips the week end dates and don t take saturdays and sundays into account.

**How could I create an index that also skips Sat and Sun ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) with filtering:

```
date_index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods = 30, freq = 'D')
print (date_index[date_index.weekday < 5])
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04',
               '2018-01-05', '2018-01-08', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10',
               '2018-01-11', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-15', '2018-01-16',
               '2018-01-17', '2018-01-18', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-22',
               '2018-01-23', '2018-01-24', '2018-01-25', '2018-01-26',
               '2018-01-29', '2018-01-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If want filter rows with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (df[df.index.weekday < 5])
```